# How to replace invalid chars to underscore using Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a string like "www.mysite.com" in $site variable.
In MySQL the Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers are (more info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html):

- ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar,
  underscore)
- Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF

However for me now would be enough to do this regular expression: 's/[^0-9a-zA-Z\$*]/*/g'

I would like to replace invalid characters of $site to make valid Schema Object Name (like database name) with underscore. Replace should be done with Perl regex.
In this example the . should be replaced with _

In Bash:

```
site="www.mysite.com"
mysql_db_name= ???
```

My problem is, that I don't know:

- **How to input $site to Perl regexp to do the replacements, then assign result to $mysql_db_name variable?**

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason that this absolutely must be perl?

Comment: I know Perl regexp much better than sed or awk, so I can debug Perl regex more easier.

Comment: And if for some reason this has to be Perl, why does it also have to use regex?

Comment: Also, Perl is based on sed and awk, and has the most complicated and hard to debug replacement system of all the alternatives being offered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mysql_db_name=$(printf %s\\n "$site" | perl -lpe 'y/0-9a-zA-Z$_/_/c')
```

Now since you know Perl well, no need for any explanations.

```
mysql_db_name=${site//[!a-zA-Z_$0-9]/_}

mysql_db_name=$(perl -se 'print y/0-9a-zA-Z$/_/cr' -- -_="$site")
```

Comment: Almost good, but result is bad: "www_mysite_com_". Has one more _ that it would need. If this is fixed, will accept as solution.

Comment: Yes, it is fixed now. Your second solution is a simple bash replacement, but AFAIK, the regex used in bash replacements are different from Perl regex. Anyway your fixed first answer works fine, so accepting as working solution.

Comment: The `bash` method is exactly what `Perl` is doing, albeit taking the less circuitous route of first having to print the variable -> then modify -> then print again. Note that Perl y/// operator DOES NOT take regexes. They are literal chars except for -.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't *have* to use perl, `tr` makes this dead simple:

```
mysql_db_name="$(echo -n "$site" | tr -C '0-9a-zA-Z_$' '_')"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution! If there would be no Perl based solution, I would accept your answer, but in this case I have closer solution to the asked one.

Comment: Sorry, but your working solution did not meet the specification (Perl regex based solution). If there would be possible, I would split the accepted answer between both of you.

Comment: No apologies necessary.

Comment: Can pass the variable directly to `tr` with a here-string:  `tr -C '0-9a-zA-Z_$' <<<"$site"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are in bash, and the value to edit is already in a variable, why do you need to use awk, perl, sed or anything if bash could do it by itself:

```
$ site="www.mysite.com"
$ mysql_db_name="${site//[^a-zA-Z0-9$]/_}"
$ echo "$mysql_db_name"
www_mysite_com
```

While the syntax for bash patterns (not regex) is different than Perl regexes, what is inside **A bracket expression.** is equivalent to both alternatives: Match **one** character from the list provided.